# ¿"Tooltip" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Últimamente me ha dado por traducir las [FAQ para Stack Exchange](http://FAQ%20for%20Stack%20Exchange%20sites) al español para Stack Overflow en español. Hoy estaba traduciendo [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681/209901) cuando me topé con la frase:

> In the past no "edit" link would be shown at all; since July 2012 the edit link [is disabled](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944) and **the mouse hover tooltip will explain** why an edit cannot be suggested, like "Account is not allowed to suggest edits".

y lo [traduje](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1580/83) como:

> En el pasado, no aparecía el enlace *editar*; desde julio de 2012 dicho enlace [aparece inhabilitado](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944) y **al pasar el ratón por encima un *tooltip* explica** por qué la edición no puede ser sugerida, diciendo por ejemplo "La cuenta no tiene permitido sugerir ediciones".

Como veis, no fui capaz de encontrar una palabra española para definir el concepto de *tooltip*.

El *tooltip* es un elemento visual que aparece en la pantalla para dar ayuda a la hora de utilizar algún elemento de la página. Más técnicamente, Wikipedia [define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip) define este concepto como:

> The tooltip or infotip or a hint is a common graphical user interface element. It is used in conjunction with a cursor, usually a pointer. The user hovers the pointer over an item, without clicking it, and a tooltip may appear—a small "hover box" with information about the item being hovered over.

y su página hermana en español se titula [información sobre herramientas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informaci%C3%B3n_sobre_herramientas) y en ella se describe como *descripción emergente* (de hecho lo veo ahora al preguntar aquí, al redactar la traducción no llegué tan lejos).

Parece suficientemente descriptivo usar *descripción emergente*, pero no dejo de tener la duda: Cuando no se usa directamente en inglés, ¿cómo se usa de forma más generalizada este concepto en castellano? ¿Es *descripción emergente* lo suficientemente explicativa?

Comment: Una alternativa a "descripción emergente" puede ser "descripción sobreimpresa".

Comment: Pista flotante/emergente, quizás, pero eso sería por la idea original.  Ahora, la gente suele usarlos más como, como dices, descripciones u otros detalles/informaciones.  Obviamente el problema al traducirlo hoy es que ni en inglés tiene tanto sentido la palabra respecto al uso cotidiano.

Comment: If it's any help it took me quite a while when i first met the term in English to work out why it was called that so I would not search for too direct a translation. Do you have a word in Spanish for tip as in a piece of useful advice?

Comment: @mdewey Yes, actually we do. The word is "tip". :-(

Comment: ¿"Cartel informativo"? I usually say "cartelito". There's nothing in the original *tooltip* that suggest the tip emerges (comes up) from somewhere, so it needn't be in the translation either.

Comment: @mdewey You can use *consejo* for *tip*, though it is true that this word is getting some use in Spanish lately, as pablodf76 says. In Spanish magazines, those *10 tips for...* sections are usually called *10 consejos para...*

Comment: Ahora que vengo de la pregunta sobre *pet peeves*, una de mis neuras favoritas es el uso de la construcción pasiva en lugar de la pasiva refleja en españo.. Yo escribiría *[...] por qué no se puede sugerir la edición [...]*

Comment: @Gorpik pues tienes toda la razón del mundo, suena mucho mejor y creo que la adoptaré como neura :)

Comment: @fedorqui Yo tengo otra neura. No me suena igual "no se puede sugerir" que "no puede sugerirse". Me parece más natural la segunda. (Aunque depende... Sería interesante una pregunta sobre la posición del "se" y los matices semánticos). Por cierto, ¿qué tal "no puede proponerse"? "Proponer" es un verbo con un significado más sobrio que el de "sugerir", que en español también significa "dar consejo". A [neurótico no me vais a ganar](https://i.imgur.com/kR2TVo7.jpg). 

Comment: @cdlvcdlv jajajaja buenísimo el comentario. A mí me gusta más _no se puede sugerir_ que _no puede sugerirse_, creo que poner el _se_ delante da más información... para gustos colores :D

Comment: @fedorqui Puede ser que sea solo cuestión de gusto. O tal vez haya casos en los que el cambio de lugar del pronombre produzca cambios semánticos o estilísticos más o menos sutiles en las construcciones perifrásticas. Si se me ocurre algún caso curioso ya plantearía la pregunta con más seriedad. La posición del "no" en las perífrasis negativas sí que cambia el sentido, aunque es un error habitual en la lengua informal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para este caso, no considero que sea algo complicado hacer el traslado del concepto del idioma inglés al español. Tomando como ejemplo:

> 1. **Tooltip** *vs.* **Información sobre herramientas**
> 2. **Tooltip** *vs.* **Descripción emergente**

Como verás, decirlo en español realmente es bastante claro, pero mucho más largo, supongo que esto puede complicar un poco una traducción más directa.

Ahora, para usarlo directamente me parece que depende mucho del contexto, esto:

> En el pasado, no aparecía el enlace editar; desde julio de 2012 dicho enlace aparece inhabilitado y al pasar el ratón por encima un *tooltip* explica por qué la edición no puede ser sugerida...

Lo traduciría así:

> En el pasado, no aparecía el enlace editar; desde julio de 2012 dicho enlace aparece inhabilitado y al pasar el ratón por encima se muestra información que  explica por qué la edición no puede ser sugerida...

O en su caso:

> En el pasado, no aparecía el enlace editar; desde julio de 2012 dicho enlace aparece inhabilitado y al pasar el ratón por encima un cuadro emergente con información que explica por qué la edición no puede ser sugerida...

En resumen, considero que la traducción *Información sobre herramientas* lo describe mejor, pero puede haber una pequeña variación para hacer uso al momento de realizar alguna traducción.

Comment: ¡Gran recomendación! En la segunda sugerencia, me suena algo mejor _aparece inhabilitado  y al pasar el ratón por encima APARECE/SE MUESTRA un cuadro emergente con información..._.